# Edit the date in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to change the date on a plugin and I was told to add this to my function code.

```
add_filter( 'uael_post_event_date', function( $date, $post_id, $date_format ) {
    // Modify the date here
    return $date;
}, 10, 3 );
```

The plugin displays a date but it is the date the post was created and I need to change it to the date of the event. Seems simple enough, I just need to find out which ID is the event date and switch it out. However, I have no idea on how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

-Shoo

Answer (score 0):

This might be working:

```
add_filter( 'uael_post_event_date', function( $date, $post_id, $date_format ) {
     $event = EEM_Event::instance()->get_one_by_ID($post_id);
     $dtt = $event->get_first_related('Datetime');
     $date_start = $dtt->get_date('DTT_EVT_start', 'M d');
     return $date_start;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This did work! Thank you! Can we easily change it so that it just shows month and day. SO currently it shows September 6, 2020 4:00 pm. Can that just be SEP 6 or would I need to write some sort of function to change instances of September to SEP?

Comment: get_date() has a second parameter "format". $dtt->get_date('DTT_EVT_start', 'M d'). I edited the code .

Comment: That was perfect! Thank you so much! I really appreciate you.

Comment: I see that you are new to SO, like me. Could you accept the answer, this is preferred to comments, since they should be reserved to clarifying info.